# How To Code Sequencing Of 2 Condition when 2nd Condition , On Which Candle It Will Happen Is Unknown Candle ,After 1st Condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

There Are 2 Condition 1st condition = A , and 2nd Condition = B

If 1st Condition =A Happens Then Look For 2nd Condition= B ( But 2nd Conditio Can HAppen On Future Candles Sometime On 1st Candle After 1st Condition , sometime More Than 1 Candle  & Even Sometime After 5 Candles)So How To Code The Seqeunce Occurance Of 2nd Condition When No's Candles Is Unknown When It Will Happen.

A= 1st Condition
B= 2nd Condition
Occurance= A[1] and B (Here B Is Only Considered If It Occurs On 2 nd Candel After A[1])
But I Want To Code In Such Way That It 2nd Condition Can be Identified Even It Occurs After 1 candle, or 2nd candle or 5 candles from 1st Condtition= A Is True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `bool` with the `var` keyword to check if `A` occurred, but then you'll need to reset it when you decide `A` is no longer relevant.

For example - let's say you want to enter position only if `B` occurred in the 5 bars after `A`. You can use:

```
var bool waitingForB = false

if A
    waitingForB := true

if A[5]
   waitingForB := false

long = B and waitingForB
```

**EDIT**

While the solution above works for some cases, there are cases where it will fail. For example - if `A` occurred on bar X, then occurred again on bar X+3, `waitingForB` still will turn to `false` on bar X+5. If this is the desired result, the solution above works great.

If on the other hand you wish to check if `A` occurred in the last 5 bars before `B`, a "safer" way of doing that is by using `ta.barssince()` function:

```
waitingForB = ta.barssince(A) < 5
long = B and waitingForB
```

Comment: Thanks But It Is Showing Condition True After 5 Bars After A.

Comment: See my edit. the second option should work as you probably intended